# Vertical text from left to right with NSTextView

Tags: swift, cocoa, webvtt

In the WebVTT video subtitle format, subtitles can be horizontal, vertical growing left, or vertical growing right. The natural text direction of `NSTextView` is horizontal; with `setLayoutOrientation(_:)` I get vertical text growing left. How can I get vertical text growing right? The documentation says that with `setLayoutOrientation(_:)` the text view's bounds are rotated by 90° clockwise, but manually rotating them by -90° with `boundsRotation = -90` just rotates everything, including the text which should have the same orientation as before, just expanding in the opposite direction.